# An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, ssl-certificate

I have a self-signed certificate and i would like to use it on my websockets server to handle requests from wss://localhost:443. I connect to the server from any web-browser.

However, i cant seem to get the authentication right. Everytime i try to connect to the WebSockets Server via Advanced Rest Client (ARC) software, i type **wss://localhost:443** or **wss://127.0.0.1:443**,

Am getting the exception

"**System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate**".

I created the certificate using openssl for windows and created a very simple certificate. Still i cant get the authentication right. Any help?

Here is how am trying to go about it with the C# code

```
var serverCertificate = new X509Certificate2("E:\\TestsFolder\\test-cert.pfx", "12345");
var certificates = new X509CertificateCollection { serverCertificate };

Stream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(stream, false,
                    (o, x509Certificate, chain, errors) => true,
                    (o, s, collection, x509Certificate, issuers) => certificates[0]);

await sslStream.AuthenticateAsServerAsync(serverCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);

WebSocketHttpContext context = await _webSocketServerFactory.ReadHttpHeaderFromStreamAsync(sslStream, source.Token);
```

What on earth could i be missing?

Here is a shot of my console with the exception

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error from ARC?  Did you add the certificate to the trusted list?

Comment: Well, after restarting the computer, i try with ARC and i get authenticated well. But when i run it from https://www.websocket.org/echo.html and browse wss://localhost:443, i get the **A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception**

Comment: Are ARC and the browser you're using to access websocket.org using the same trusted certificate root list?

Comment: They are surely using the same certificate. The websockets server is running as a console application. Both the browser and ARC are accessing it with the same address as mentioned above

Comment: Of course they're using the same certificate.  The question is whether they both trust that certificate.  Chrome uses the Windows trusted root CA list, Firefox has a different list, etc.  If ARC is a desktop app, it's likely using the Windows list.  One thing to do is to open the websocket.org page in Chrome, open the developer tools, and see what's reported in the Network tab when you try to connect to your endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We made our websockets server to use TLS 1.2.

Adding manually:

```
ws.SslConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
```

solved the issue.